# How to print an isosceles triangle

Tags: c#, loops, geometry

I'm trying to learn programming by myself, I'm working from a book that has the following problem which I can't solve:

> Allow the user to input two values: a character to be used for printing an isosceles triangle and the size of the peak for the triangle. For example, if the user inputs # for the character and 6 for the peak, you should produce the following display:

#

##

###

####

#####

######

#####

####

###

##

#

This is the code I've got so far:

```
        char character;
        int peak;

        InputValues(out character, out peak);

        for (int row = 1; row < peak * 2; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 1; col <= row; col++)
            {                    
                Console.Write(character);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.Read() // hold console open
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int row = 0; row < peak; row++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(new string(character, row + 1));
}
for (int row = 1; row < peak; row++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(new string(character, peak - row));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Close, but you want to start decreasing when you're going 'back down'.
You can either do two loops;
 `0 -> peak`, then `(peak - 1 -> 0)`, which will print both 'directions'.

An alternative is to find out how far away from the peak you are in terms of rows, and print out that many characters.

```
    for (int row = 0; row < peak*2; row++)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < peak -  Math.Abs(row - peak); i++)
            Console.Write(character);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: + 1 nice but why not write the line with `new string(character, peak - Math.Abs(row-peak))` and drop the second for

Comment: Was trying to keep it as close to his code as possible, to focus on the logic of the code rather than the syntax

Answer (score 1):

Slight alternative to Yuriy Faktorovich's answer (I never get to use step downs so I couldn't resist)

warning not tested

```
for (int row = 0; row < peak; row++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(new string(character, row + 1));
}
for (int row = peak, row > 1; row--)
{
    Console.WriteLine(new string(character, row));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way i WOuld Do it :

```
    static void drawIsoscelesTraiangle(char repeatChar, int peak, int current)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < peak; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new String(repeatChar, current++));
        }
        for (int i = current; i > 0; i--)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new String(repeatChar, current--));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version with a loop and a version with LINQ...

```
Console.WriteLine("peak");
var peak = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("char");
var @char = (char)Console.Read();

//As LINQ
var query = (from row in Enumerable.Range(0, peak * 2)
             let count = peak - Math.Abs(peak - row)
             let str = new string(@char, count)
             select str
            ).ToArray(); //if you have .Net 4.0+ you don't need the .ToArray()
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, query));

//As Loop
for (int r = 1; r < peak * 2; r++)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", new string(@char, peak - Math.Abs(peak - r)));
Console.Read(); // hold console open
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char drawChar = '#';
            int repeatNumber = 5;
        Program.drawIsoscelesTraiangle(drawChar, repeatNumber, 1);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static void drawIsoscelesTraiangle(char repeatChar, int peak, int current)
    {
        if (current < peak)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new string(repeatChar, current));
            Program.drawIsoscelesTraiangle(repeatChar, peak, current + 1);
            Console.WriteLine(new string(repeatChar, current));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new string(repeatChar, current));
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have not taken care of getting the user inputs but rather hard coded it. But if I didn't understand incorrectly, this is what you wanted. It is very simple if you give it a thought :) This uses a tactic called 'recursion' which you should learn in case you have not, yet.

Hope this helps. Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace Ch6ex10
{
    class Isosceles
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            OutputTraiangle(InputCharacter(), InputPeak());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        //Allow user to input a character to be used as the triangle
        public static char InputCharacter()
        {
            string inputValue;
            char character;

            Console.Write("Enter the character to be used to display the  triangle: ");
            inputValue = Console.ReadLine();
            character = Convert.ToChar(inputValue);
            return character;
        }

        //Allow user to input an integer for the peak of the triangle
        public static int InputPeak()
        {
            string inputPeak;
            int peak;

            Console.Write("Enter the integer amount for the peak of the triangle: ");
            inputPeak = Console.ReadLine();
            peak = Convert.ToInt32(inputPeak);
            return peak;
        }

        //Output the triangle using the users character choice and peak size (first half)
        public static void OutputTraiangle(char character, int peak)
        {
            int start = 1;
            int finish = (peak - 1);

            while (start != peak)
            {
                for (int amount = 1; amount <= start; amount++)
                {
                    Console.Write(character);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                start++;                
            }

            for (int amount = 1; amount <= peak; amount++)
                {
                     Console.Write(character);
                }
            Console.WriteLine();

            while (finish != 0)
            {
                for (int amount = 1; amount <= finish; amount++)
                {
                    Console.Write(character);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                finish--;
            }            
        }
    }
}
```